# How to load ocamlmktop result in aquamacs?

Tags: ocaml

I am basically executing:

```
ocamlmktop -o mytoplevel 1.cmo 2.cmo
```

and I get by an executable toplevel. The question is how do I make aquamacs run that toplevel?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the Emacs mode that you use to develop in OCaml under Aquamacs.  As `tuareg-mode` is by far the most popular choice, I consider this case.

You usually start an OCaml toplevel with the command `M-x tuareg-run-ocaml` which prompts for a toplevel to start. You can here enter the path to your custom toplevel.

The toplevel proposed by `tuareg-run-ocaml` is actually the value of the variable `tuareg-interactive-program`, you can take advantage of this to define a custom `tuareg-run-mytoplevel` function with:

```
(defun tuareg-run-mytoplevel ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((tuareg-interactive-program "/path/to/mytoplevel"))
    (tuareg-run-ocaml)))
```

If you put this definition in your `~/.emacs`, you can then use the command `M-x tuareg-run-mytoplevel` to start your own toplevel.